# Simple partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

I am learning partial derivatives. I am stuck in understanding the concept. I am expressing the question in form of problems below:

Problem1:
$z = xy$, $x$ & $y$ are independent of each other.

what is change in $z$, $\Delta z$, at $x = 1, y = 1$,
due to small change in $x$, $\Delta x = 0.001$ and a small change in $y$,  $\Delta y = 0.001$

Problem2:
$z = xy$

Also $y = x$ (i,e $y$ is function of $x$)
what is change in $z$, $\Delta z$, at $x = 1, y = 1$
due to small change in $x$, $\Delta x = 0.001$ and a small change in $y$, $\Delta y = 0.001$

Thanks in advance for answers.

---

I found the explanation here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Differentiation_with_indirect_dependencies
thanks 5xum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function $f$ of two variables, you can use the estimate $$f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)\approx f(x,y) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)\cdot\Delta x + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\right)\cdot \Delta y.$$

For a function $f$ of one variable, that simplifies to $$f(x+\Delta x)\approx f(x) + f'(x)\Delta x$$

Comment: Yes using the above formula I get the answer for problem 1 as 0.002

Comment: Now in Problem 2:
I can take it as z = x^2, since y = x
solving I will get change in z as 0.002
Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. In problem one, you get $\Delta z = \Delta x + \Delta y = 0.002$ as the partial derivatives equal $1$. In problem two, the function is $x^2$ so the derivative is equal to $2$ and $\Delta z = 2\Delta x = 0.002$

Comment: please edit your comment with dollar signs, it is unreadable at the moment.

Comment: But i can also solve Problem2 this way:
$$\Delta z = \left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right )\Delta x +\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right )\Delta y$$

Now $$z = x^2$$
so,  
$$\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right )\Delta x = \left ( 2x \right )\Delta x = 0.002$$

and  
$$\left ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right )\Delta y = x\Delta y=0.001  $$

So $$\Delta z = 0.003$$

Comment: No. If $z=x^2$, then $\partial z/\partial y = 0.$

Comment: But 
$$\partial z/\partial y \neq  0$$
How come making y=x make it 
$$\partial z/\partial y=0$$
Still z = xy, so changing y should change z

Comment: For $z=x^2$, you have $\partial z/\partial x = 2x$ and $\partial z/\partial y = 0$. For $z=xy$, you have $\partial z\partial x=y$ and $\partial z/\partial y = x$. You can't take one derivative from $z=x^2$ and the other from $z=xy$.

Comment: Lets say there is one small circular metal disc
On side it is heated. 
Now since it is heated, it can absorb some energy, its temperature
increases and its radius increases.

Comment: Also we can increase its radius directly by stretching

Now lets say the metal disc release the heat on other side

This energy released, depends on its temperature & its surface area.


Now at some instant the heating temperature is increased by small amount
and also its radius is increased by streatching.
Now we have to find the increase in energy released by this metal disc.

Shouldn't we consider the increase in radius two times?
One due to increase in temperature of plate
& another due to increase in streatching?

Comment: Yes, and that is why you have $2\Delta x$ for $z=x^2$. The $2$ comes from your explanation.